# Deleted my git folder

Tags: git, pull

I had a git folder on my desktop which I share with colleagues but I've deleted the folder and have no idea how to get it back (it was set up by a colleague).  I tried making a folder with the same name and doing a git-pull but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `git clone` to the repository used with your colleagues. You must know git repository adress (where the git server host the folder)

Syntax : `git clone gitUrl`

The `gitUrl` as to be given by your colleagues

Documentation : [Git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

Answer (score 0):

Simply making a new folder won't work, because git doesn't know the details of the repository based on just the name. There's actually a folder in each cloned repository that you can go look at (but probably not a good idea to edit) called `.git`.

You'll need to clone the repository again using git clone . This url can be in ssh format or http, for example:

`git clone https://github.com/<owner>/<repository_name>.git`

or

`git clone ssh://user@address/<path_to_repo>/<repository_name>.git`

Note that if you use ssh urls you won't need a username and password, but you will need to set up some [keys](http://github.com/settings/keys).

After your clone the repository locally again, as your coworkers make changes you can `git fetch` and `git pull` the changes to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

like another answer. it easy if you have to make `git clone` again from your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Another way than `git clone` would be:

`git remote add origin gitUrl`

`git pull`

`origin` is default name of your local repository. Instead of it you can choose your own name for repository.